# Refreshing a binding source after add, update or delete

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I needed to know if there is a way to refresh a binding source after adding, updating or deleting records such that in the case of deleting a record, i will be able to show the proper record count in my binding navigator tool bar.

I am making a payroll application module for adding banks at the moment. I am unable to add two consecutive records (can only add one at a time right now, close my app, then add another). My application is integrated to SAP Business 1.

On my BankMasterForm.cs I have

```
private void BankMaintenanceForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bankMasterBindingSource.DataSource = Program.Kernel.Get<IBankMasterService>().GetAllBankMasters();
}
```

I am also using the Ninject addon for this application

My code on the IBankMasterService.cs (the interface)form:

```
namespace Payroll.BLL
{
    public interface IBankMasterService
    {
        IEnumerable<BankMaster> GetAllBankMasters();

        BankMaster GetBankMaster(string code);

        void AddBankMaster(BankMaster bankMaster);

        void UpdateBankMaster(BankMaster bankMaster);

        void DeleteBankMaster(BankMaster bankMaster);

        string GenerateSAPCode();
    }
}
```

I also have the BankMasterService.cs class:

```
namespace Payroll.BLL
{
    public class BankMasterService : IBankMasterService
    {
        private readonly IBankMasterRepository _bankMasterRepository;

        public BankMasterService(
            IBankMasterRepository bankMasterRepository)
        {
            Guard.AgainstNullParameter(bankMasterRepository, "bankMasterRepository");

            _bankMasterRepository = bankMasterRepository;
        }

        public IEnumerable<BankMaster> GetAllBankMasters()
        {
            return _bankMasterRepository.SelectAll();
        }

        public BankMaster GetBankMaster(string code)
        {
            var rulesException = new RulesException<BankMaster>();

            // Business rule: Answer Id cannot be less than 1
            if (!code.HasValue())
                rulesException.ErrorFor(x => x.Code, "Code cannot be null");

            if (rulesException.Errors.Any()) throw rulesException;

            return _bankMasterRepository.GetEntity(code);
        }

        public void AddBankMaster(BankMaster bankMaster)
        {
            // Business rule: 0
            var errors = DataAnnotationsValidationRunner.GetErrors(bankMaster);

            var rulesException = new RulesException();

            rulesException.ErrorsForModel(errors);

            // Other validation rules

            if (rulesException.Errors.Any()) throw rulesException;

            // Save to database
            _bankMasterRepository.Insert(bankMaster);
        }

        public void UpdateBankMaster(BankMaster bankMaster)
        {
            // Business rule: 0
            var errors = DataAnnotationsValidationRunner.GetErrors(bankMaster);

            var rulesException = new RulesException();

            rulesException.ErrorsForModel(errors);

            // Other validation rules

            if (rulesException.Errors.Any()) throw rulesException;

            // Save to database
            _bankMasterRepository.Update(bankMaster);
        }

        public void DeleteBankMaster(BankMaster bankMaster)
        {
            var bm = GetBankMaster(bankMaster.Code);

            if (bm != null)
            {
                // Delete from database
                _bankMasterRepository.Delete(bm);
            }
        }

        public string GenerateSAPCode()
        {
            var result = default(long);

            var codesList = from b in GetAllBankMasters()
                            select new { Code = long.Parse(b.Code) };

            codesList = codesList.OrderBy(x => x.Code);

            var lastRecord = codesList.LastOrDefault();

            if (lastRecord != null)
                result = lastRecord.Code + 1;

            return result.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

An example delete function on my BankMasterForm.cs form is:

```
private void bindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Record?", "Confirm", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        // Get service instance
        var bankMasterService = Program.Kernel.Get<IBankMasterService>();

        var bankMasterDelete =
                new BankMaster
                {
                    Code = txt_code.Text
                };

        // Delete record
        bankMasterService.DeleteBankMaster(bankMasterDelete);

        //clear textfields after input
        txt_code.Text = string.Empty;
        txt_bank_code.Text = string.Empty;
        txt_bank_name.Text = string.Empty;
        cb_bank_type.Text = null;
        txt_address1.Text = string.Empty;
        txt_address2.Text = string.Empty;
        txt_comments.Text = string.Empty;

        MessageBox.Show("Bank Details Deleted Successfully");
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I get my binding source, i.e.:

```
bankMasterBindingSource.DataSource = Program.Kernel.Get<IBankMasterService>().GetAllBankMasters();
```

to refresh after a delete for example?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this a Winforms application, or some other UI toolkit?  This information should be added to the quesiton, and possibly to the tags.

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham. It is a SAP Business 1 add on - Windows forms app

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that the .ResetBindings() call forces it to refresh the list.

But, if you are doing a GUI operation it's better to use the binding source to execute the delete.  That way you can use the validation properties of the form etc. and then implement the infrastructure underneath to do the job that you need done.  Imagine a multi client system where many changes are occurring at once the list would refresh constantly.  As such the binding source allows you to abstract when and how often your view changes, but is geared to maintain a local state that has some level of sanity in it.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I dont know how to use the binding source to execute the delete. I'll have to research on that

Comment: Your list should implement IList.  IList has a .Remove function.  If you bind an IList to a binding source, calling BindingSource.Remove will execute a .Remove on your IList for the bound item.  This in turn would then execute your delete logic written for your implementation of .Remove on your IList.

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer. Just add this line of code after every edit or adding of a record. It refreshes the binding source.

```
// Refresh the datasource
bankMasterBindingSource.DataSource = Program.Kernel.Get<IBankMasterService>().GetAllBankMasters().ToList();
```

This way, the newly added or updated records can be "seen" by the system